# How to restore tensorflow inceptions checkpoint file (ckpt)?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have `inception_resnet_v2_2016_08_30.ckpt` file which is a pre-trained inception model. I want to restore this model using

`saver.restore(sess, ckpt_filename)`

But for that, I will be required to write the set of variables that were used while training this model. Where can I find those (a script, or detailed description)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of you have get the network architecture in memory. You can get the network architecture from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/slim/nets/inception_resnet_v2.py)

Once you have this program with you, use the following approach to use the model:

```
from inception_resnet_v2 import inception_resnet_v2, inception_resnet_v2_arg_scope

height = 299
width = 299
channels = 3

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, height, width, channels])
with slim.arg_scope(inception_resnet_v2_arg_scope()):
     logits, end_points = inception_resnet_v2(X, num_classes=1001,is_training=False)
```

With this you have all the network in memory, Now you can initialize the network with checkpoint file(ckpt) by using tf.train.saver:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
sess = tf.Session()
saver.restore(sess, "/home/pramod/Downloads/inception_resnet_v2_2016_08_30.ckpt")
```

If you want to do bottle extractions, its simple like lets say you want to get features from last layer, then simply you have to declare `predictions = end_points["Logits"]`
If you want to get it for other intermediate layer, you can get those names from the above program inception_resnet_v2.py

After that you can call: `output =  sess.run(predictions, feed_dict={X:batch_images})`

Comment: You need to `import tensorflow.contrib.slim as slim` to use `slim.arg_scope`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the [`MetaGraph` mechanism](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/how_tos/meta_graph/index.html)  is what you need.

EDIT: additionally, take a look at `tf.train.NewCheckpointReader` -- it has a `get_variable_to_shape_map()` method.  See [unit test](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/saver_test.py#L1630).

Comment: Thanks but MetaGraph helps in loading model definition. All I have currently is a checkpoint model which contains just the values for trained weights and biases (and no information about model architecture, etc.)