# C# TensorFlow inceptionModel(.ckpt) restore and make a frozen model file(.pb)

Tags: c#, tensorflow, tensorflow-slim

I want to download [inception_resnet_v2](http://download.tensorflow.org/models/ens_adv_inception_resnet_v2_2017_08_18.tar.gz) and restore it and make a frozen model file.(.PB) for C# tensorflow program.

Reference: [How to restore tensorflow inceptions checkpoint file (ckpt)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983591/how-to-restore-tensorflow-inceptions-checkpoint-file-ckpt)

Python code here:

```
import tensorflow as tf
slim = tf.contrib.slim

from inception_resnet_v2 import inception_resnet_v2, inception_resnet_v2_arg_scope

height = 299
width = 299
channels = 3

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, height, width, channels])
with slim.arg_scope(inception_resnet_v2_arg_scope()):
     logits, end_points = inception_resnet_v2(X, num_classes=1001,is_training=False)

saver = tf.train.Saver()
sess = tf.Session()
saver.restore(sess, "./inception_resnet_v2_2016_08_30.ckpt")

tf.train.write_graph( sess.graph_def, "./pb", 'inception_resnet_v2_2016_08_30.pb', as_text=True)
```

and the [inception_resnet_v2](https://github.com/tensorflow/cleverhans/blob/master/examples/nips17_adversarial_competition/sample_defenses/ens_adv_inception_resnet_v2/inception_resnet_v2.py)

inception_resnet_v2_2016_08_30.ckpt [226MB]

inception_resnet_v2_2016_08_30.pb [6MB]

The output file is incorrect.

How to get the full .pb file?

make a frozen model file reference :
github.com/migueldeicaza/TensorFlowSharp/issues/85#issuecomment-313590825

The Command:

```
python .\Python\Python35\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\tools\freeze_graph.py --   input_graph=.\inception_resnet_v2_2016_08_30.pb --input_checkpoint=.\inception_resnet_v2_2016_08_30.ckpt --output_node_names=Output/Predictions,Output/Loss --output_graph=inception_resnet_v2_2016_08_30_out.pb
```

Error:AssertionError: Output/Predictions is not in graph

Comment: The error means your graph doesn't have Output/Predictions. Can you use a node name which is in the graph? Or add one, with a tf.identity(predictions, name="Output/Predictions")